# c# - Display message on textbox if SQL query has been created

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am making a program in c# where when I press a button, it will generate SQL table to my SQL server database. Message should be displayed on a big textbox screen on my program if the table has been created successfully, otherwise it should display a message error on the textbox screen.

So far, everything works as expected but no matter how many times I press the button, it will keep popping the same display message (the table has been created) to the screen.
I only want the message to show up(successfully) if the table doesn't exist yet in my database. If the table already exists, it should display a error message on screen. I am thinking a using a while statement but couldn't figure how it solve it.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnCreateTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST','U') IS NULL ";
    query += "BEGIN ";
    query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST]( "; 
    query += "[AuditID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[AuditType] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CardTypeBenefitID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CardTypeGroupID] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
    query += "[AgeFrom] [int] NULL, ";
    query += "[AgeTo] [int] NULL, ";
    query += "[Gender] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
    query += "[CreateBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL ";
    query += ") ON [PRIMARY] ";
    query += "END ";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
           {
               cmd.Connection = con;
               con.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               Display("AuditCardTypeBenefit_Test table has been created successfully");
               con.Close();
           }
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}", Environment.NewLine));
         textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}{2}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine));
         Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message));
    }
```

Note:The Display method is responsible for showing the message to the screen.

Comment: *no matter how many times I press the button, it will keep popping the same display message to the screen* What do you mean same message? Which message?

Comment: What are you going to do with a while statement?

Comment: The message "AuditCardTypeBenefit_Test table has been created successfully"

Comment: Actually the more i think about it, it not's really possible because of my query stating if a table doesn't exist, create the table. This case will always ensures my sql query execute without any error since it checks if there is the table of same name in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` method returns the number of affected rows.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1**.

Maybe doing

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNoneQuery() == -1)
  Display("AuditCardTypeBenefit_Test table has been created successfully");

con.Close();
```

will solve your problem? Don't know if it just returns 0 when creating a table, is just a suggestion.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Is this even a good practice of running sql queries? As I have multiple SQL script files, I was thinking of executing these files rather than hard coding these queries in c#. Imagine if I have 50 sql scripts and I have to include into the code, it's going to be tedious.

Comment: I tried your code, it's still the same issue. It still generate that message when the table already exists in my sql server. which it should not do that.

Comment: I won't say its good or bad practice, that pretty much depends on the situation. Sometimes creating tables on the fly is required. However, if you have the script files and there is no need to generate the tables from your application, then why not use them?

Comment: What do you mean use them?

Comment: I was skeptical as first but my superior wants me to make this program to execute these sql script files for data archiving purposes. I was thinking why not executing the scripts manually in SSMS instead, if that's what you're proposing.

Comment: That is what I was proposing.

Comment: To be honest I thought of that but well, my superior wants me to design a program which is why i was confused.